# Как оправить данные с формы с инпутом type="file" через ajax + номер?

Tags: ajax, form

```
 <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="jsrachet" >
    <input type="tel" class="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Введите номер">
    <label class="file">
                      <input type="file" name="upload" value="Прикрепить файл"><span>Выберите файл</span></label>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn jscalculation">Получить просчет </button> </form>


    $("#jsrachet").submit(function(){
                   const input = $('input[type=file]');
                   const files = input[0].files;
                   const formData = new FormData;
                   formData.append('upload',files[0]);
               $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"rachet.php",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    datatype:'json',
                    success:function(){
                      $("#messagezayavka").addClass("active");  
                    },


            });
                   return false; 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const files = input[0].files;
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('upload', files[0]);
formData.append('phone', $(this).find(".tel").val());
```

или проще:

```
var formData = new FormData(this);
```

Comment: А как через форм дата еще и номер переслать фместе с файлом ,фаил опрпвился только номер с формы пустой приходит ?